# Exception: cannot instantiate 'PosixPath' on your system

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have this code

```py
# Importar librerias
import torch
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Leemos el modelo
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='best.pt', force_reload=True)

# Realizamos VideoCaptura
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

# Empezamos
while True:
     # Realizar lectura de la videocaptura
     ret, frame = cap.read()

     # Realisms detection
     detect = model(frame)

     # Mostramos FPS
     cv2.imshow('Detector de Guineo', np.squeeze(detect.render()))

     # Leer el teclado
     t = cv2.waitKey(5)
     if t == 27:
         break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But when it is executed I get this error, any idea how to solve it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP/.cache\torch\hub\ultralytics_yolov5_master\hubconf.py", line 50, in _create
    model = DetectMultiBackend(path, device=device, fuse=autoshape)  # detection model
  File "C:\Users\HP/.cache\torch\hub\ultralytics_yolov5_master\models\common.py", line 467, in __init__
    model = attempt_load(weights if isinstance(weights, list) else w, device=device, inplace=True, fuse=fuse)
  File "C:\Users\HP/.cache\torch\hub\ultralytics_yolov5_master\models\experimental.py", line 97, in attempt_load
    ckpt = torch.load(attempt_download(w), map_location="cpu")  # load
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 1026, in load
    return _load(opened_zipfile,
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 1438, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\pathlib.py", line 1084, in __new__
    raise NotImplementedError("cannot instantiate %r on your system"
NotImplementedError: cannot instantiate 'PosixPath' on your system

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP/.cache\torch\hub\ultralytics_yolov5_master\hubconf.py", line 65, in _create
    model = attempt_load(path, device=device, fuse=False)  # arbitrary model
  File "C:\Users\HP/.cache\torch\hub\ultralytics_yolov5_master\models\experimental.py", line 97, in attempt_load
    ckpt = torch.load(attempt_download(w), map_location="cpu")  # load
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 1026, in load
    return _load(opened_zipfile,
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 1438, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\pathlib.py", line 1084, in __new__
    raise NotImplementedError("cannot instantiate %r on your system"
NotImplementedError: cannot instantiate 'PosixPath' on your system

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\HP\OneDrive - Universidad Politecnica Salesiana\Escritorio\Prueba\Ia.py", line 7, in <module>
    model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='best.pt', force_reload=True)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 566, in load
    model = _load_local(repo_or_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 595, in _load_local
    model = entry(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP/.cache\torch\hub\ultralytics_yolov5_master\hubconf.py", line 88, in custom
    return _create(path, autoshape=autoshape, verbose=_verbose, device=device)
  File "C:\Users\HP/.cache\torch\hub\ultralytics_yolov5_master\hubconf.py", line 83, in _create
    raise Exception(s) from e
Exception: cannot instantiate 'PosixPath' on your system. Cache may be out of date, try `force_reload=True` or see https://docs.ultralytics.com/yolov5/tutorials/pytorch_hub_model_loading for help.
```

Comment: POSIX is from UNIXy systems. You can't unpickle a PosixPath object on Windows because it isn't supported there.

Comment: Anyhow, using pickled models is a serious security risk; there are newer/better serialization formats that don't do arbitrary code execution, so it's best to avoid them altogether. If you don't know if _this particular_ model is available in a non-pickle format, the place for to ask for support [is their discord](https://discord.gg/n6cFeSPZdD) or [their GitHub repo](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues).

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't support `PosixPath` objects, hence the `NotImplementedError`.

One solution is to retrain your model on a Windows machine and save the model file there. This way, the saved model file will contain `WindowsPath` objects, which can be loaded on your Windows machine without issues.